# UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) is returning false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am working on the ForgotPassword section of my site.  When I test it I have a breakpoint in the function and I can see that this line of code is returning false:

```
(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
```

I have verified that EmailConfirmed field in the AspNetUsers table is set to True.  Why would this still be returning false?

Here is the first part of the Account Controller where it initializes the UserManager:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set 
        { 
            _signInManager = value; 
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Found the requested Owin string in my Startup.Auth.cs class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct database?

Comment: That's a good question.  I am assuming that function is using the correct DB, but how do I verify?

Comment: How do you create `UserManager`? What is the connection string called? And what is the constructor of the context?

Comment: I have three of my own contexts but it looks like it is calling GetOwinContext().  I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: I think I provided everything you asked for.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have a line telling `OwinContext` how to create the user manager object, something like this: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80064/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-davidg).

Answer (score 0):

You are likely pointing to the wrong database. The default templates for an MVC project with Identity will have code like this in the context:

```
public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

This is then used by `OwinContext` as the method to create your context, and as such means that it will take the connection string from your `web.config` file called `DefaultConnection`. So you have 2 choices:

1. Fix the connection string to point to the correct database.

   ```
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        connectionString="correct details here" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```
2. Change the create method to return the context with a specific connection string:

   ```
   public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
   {
       return new ApplicationDbContext("NameOfConnectionStringHere");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))` always returns false when `EmailConfirmed` is set to `False` in `AspNetUsers` SQL table.

Comment: This is exactly right.  The next question is to ask how to set it to true!